# How to keep track of DIV's child element count in runtime?

Tags: javascript, jquery, addeventlistener, event-listener

I have a div, which will contain dropdowns and these dropdowns are created dynamically by the user on the click oo a button which is kept outside this div.

So what I need to achieve here is I wanna display 'No filter applied' when there are no dropdowns and remove that 'No filter applied' while there are dropdowns present.

I tried this scenario through `addEventListener` but I am not sure what action needs to implement for this scenario?

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
  var activities = document.getElementById("dvContainer");
  activities.addEventListener("change", function() {
    if (activities.childElementCount > 0) {
      activities.classList.add("displayZero");
    } else {
      activities.classList.remove("displayZero");
    }
    //console.log('ajay');
  });
});

function AddDropDownList() {}
```

```html
<input type="button" id="btnAdd" onclick="AddDropDownList()" value="Add Filter" />
<div id="dvContainer"><span>No Filters applied.</span></div>
```

This is my try, thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you please post your HTML.

Comment: You would have to check it after every time the add/remove dropdown function has been called.

Comment: @UllasHunka 

<input type="button" id = "btnAdd" onclick = "AddDropDownList()" value = "Add Filter" />
<div id="dvContainer"><span>No Filters applied.</span></div>

Comment: so, AddDropDownList() function will target my div #dvContainer and creates the dropdown on the click of button.

Comment: $("body").on('DOMSubtreeModified', "#dvContainer", function() {
    // code here
});

Comment: AddDropDownList() can you show the example code!

Comment: @UllasHunka sorry, too long to post.

Comment: @Lain Hi Lain, alright, so I will get the count after every step, be it adding or removing, and how do I manipulate with that count?

Comment: @user3743028: Manipulate what? As far as I see you just want to add/remove a class which you seem to be doing fine.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/xp59q06y/1/ @UllasHunka

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/xp59q06y/8/ You can not check for `childElementCount` since the `span`is one itself. Just check for `select` child elements.

Comment: Lain, made it work somehow. I will share the code thru jsfiddle.

Comment: Thanks a lot Lain @Lain

Comment: Also @Lain, in the jsfiddle, initially when I shared it, i clicked on add filter button and I got an error saying function adddropdownlist() is not defined in the console, do I have to add any dependency to jsfiddle?

Comment: No, just set the javascript load type as bottom of head.

Answer (score 0):

According to what you mentioned, you have a button that with click it, you add dropdowns dynamically.

**so you don't need any extra event!!**

in your button's click function:

```
yourButton.onclick=function(){
    //..... do somethings similar adding dropdowns
    activities.classList.add("displayZero");
};
```

And where you remove dropdown:

```
activities.classList.remove("displayZero");
```

Answer (score 0):

Currently, I can think of only 2 ways to resolve:

1. The Easiest solution is first to create `update` function then call it from `init` of dom and then in the `AddDropDownList`. E.g.

```js
function update() {
  if (activities.childElementCount > 0) {
    activities.classList.add("displayZero");
  } else {
    activities.classList.remove("displayZero");
  }
}
window.onload = function() {
  update();
}

function AddDropDownList() {
  //Put Your code as you have written and then add
  update();
}
```

2. Use Mutation Observer

```js
window.onload = function() {
  // Select the node that will be observed for mutations
  var targetNode = document.getElementById('dvContainer');

  // Options for the observer (which mutations to observe)
  var config = {
    attributes: true,
    childList: true,
    subtree: true
  };
  // Create an observer instance linked to the callback function
  var observer = new MutationObserver(callback);

  // Start observing the target node for configured mutations
  observer.observe(targetNode, config);
}

function AddDropDownList() {

}


// Callback function to execute when mutations are observed
var callback = function(mutationsList) {
  for (var mutation of mutationsList) {
    if (mutation.type == 'childList') {
      console.log('A child node has been added or removed.');
      if (activities.childElementCount > 0) {
        activities.classList.add("displayZero");
      } else {
        activities.classList.remove("displayZero");
      }
    } else if (mutation.type == 'attributes') {
      console.log('The ' + mutation.attributeName + ' attribute was modified.');
    }
  }
};
```